# Symfony2 - Showing dynamic selectable roles

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I'm using Symfony2 with Sonata.
I have a list of sections on my application to which I'd like to give access to my users.

Example:

- John should have access to section1 and section3
- Bob should have access to section2 and section3

So I created 3 roles, that I can attach to users/groups (through sonata)

- ROLE_SECTION1
- ROLE_SECTION2
- ROLE_SECTION3

But as I create new sections, I'd like to have the related roles automatically listed in the admin
(without having to declare them each time in my `security.yml`)

I saw sonata-admin-user does that when using the role security handler,
but I don't know how to do the same.

Finally the question is simple and is the following:

How can I add some dynamic selectable roles into my Sonata user admin bundle editor list ?

Comment: i'm looking for the same.. if you have found anything please shre :)

Comment: You should vote up then :) (Didn't found anything yet)

Answer (score 0):

First you can load user and groups from your database. See [Symfony2 cookbook Load user from database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html). Then in the controller of every section:

```
if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('Role_section1') === false) {
    echo 'forbidden';
}
```